# iOS Development: Why doesn't the Phone Keyboard display when I specify UIKeyboardTypePhonePad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

In my view, I have a textfield setup to display [the Phone Keyboard](http://gprince.yolasite.com/resources/Phone%20Pad.jpg), but it just shows [the standard keyboard](http://ipadnotebook.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/number-keys.png) instead.  Here's my code...

```
    contactPhoneTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frameText];
    contactPhoneTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    contactPhoneTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    contactPhoneTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
    contactPhoneTextField.placeholder = @"Tap To Enter Contact Phone Number";
    contactPhoneTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    contactPhoneTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;  
    contactPhoneTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad; //<<<----
    contactPhoneTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;  
    contactPhoneTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;        
    contactPhoneTextField.delegate = self;
```

What gives?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: You may want to condider making your own keyboard as a .xib and using that as the UITextField inputView. I have done this in the past with great success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you're using an iPad? There is no phone pad available on this device … So the displayed keyboard layout with numbers is correct.

Comment: Yeah, I am using an iPad.  Thanks moosgummi!